# Как спрятать форму отправки сообщения без css?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте!

Пишу форму отправки сообщения. Есть форма, заполняете поля, данные уходят на сервер. Форма должна пропасть и на ее месте появится "Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено".

Правильно ли это делать через css примерно так

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save_report.php',
        type: 'post',
        scriptCharset: "windows-1251",
        data: $('form').serialize()
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#report').css('display', 'none');
        $('#save-report p').css('display', 'block');
        $('#save-report p').text(data);
    });
});
```

data - Ответ сервера об успешной отправке сообщения..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте hide и show смысл такой же, но код более читабельным будет..

```
    $('#report').hide();
    $('#save-report p').show();
    $('#save-report p').text(data);
```

плюс можно управлять анимацией скрытия/отображения через аргументы. [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)  [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)